# How to setup gobblin in windows ? What should be the version of gradle and gobblin?

Tags: windows, gradle, gobblin

I am trying to setup gobblin in my system, but facing issue while building gradle.
Which verion of gobblin and gradle do I need to use ?

Error :-
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'pegasus' not found.

Comment: It complains about a plugin called "pegasus". What is that?

Answer (score 1):

Pegasus is used to generate classes from template files for a REST api. It looks like it's not compatible with Windows currently.

In the meantime, could you try running Gobblin on Docker? If it's just to test the system this can be sufficient. https://github.com/apache/gobblin/blob/master/gobblin-docs/user-guide/Docker-Integration.md

Comment: Thanks for your response. Wil try this.